# Python - 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, image-processing, int, formula, magic-methods

I've searched the site, it is true there are other topics with the same name and the same problems, but I tried to read and apply the changes to my program with no results, so I decided to open a new one.

I need to create a class Pixels (which I created with no problem), and a class `PImage`, which instead I found the problem:
(carry only the most important methods)

class Pixel:

```
class Pixel(object):
    def __init__(self, r, g, b, op): // op = opacity
        self.r, self.g, self.b, self.op = r, g, b, op

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.r-other.r,self.g-other.g,self.b-other.b
```

class PImage

```
class PImage(object):
    def __init__(self, fname=None, size=None):
        if(fname!=None):
            img_app = image.load(fname)
            self.immagine = img_app
            w, h = len(img_app[0]), len(img_app)

            for j in range(h):
                for i in range(w):
                    self.immagine[j][i] = [Pixel(img_app[j][i][0], img_app[j][i][1], img_app[j][i][2], 255)]

        elif(size!=None):
            self.immagine = image.create(size[0], size[1], (0,0,0, 255))

    def size(self):
        return len(self.immagine[0]), len(self.immagine)

    def get_pixel(self, x, y):
        if image.inside(x, y, self.immagine):
            return self.immagine[y][x]
        else:
            return None

    def opacity(self, x, y, t=150):
        w, h = len(self.immagine[0]), len(self.immagine)
        for j in range(h):
            for i in range(w):
                d = abs(self.get_pixel(x, x) - x) + abs(self.get_pixel(y, y) - y) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][0] - self.immagine[y][x][0]) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][1] - self.immagine[y][x][1]) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][2] - self.immagine[y][x][2])
                self.immagine[j][i][3] = (d*self.immagine[j][i][3])/(d + t)
```

The variable `d`, I have to apply a formula made up as follows (here I get out of the error):

```
d = abs (xp - x) + abs (yp - y) + abs (rp - r) + abs (gp - g) + abs (bp - b)
```

where `(xp, yp), (rp, gp, bp) op` are, respectively, the position, color and
   the opacity of `p`, and `(r, g, b)` is the color of the pixel in position `(x, y)`.

Traceback:

I tried manually, and when the program calls `words.opacity(100, 160)`, the program returns the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-3e2e34f8ee0f> in <module>()
----> 1 words.opacity(100, 160)

/home/user/Scrivania/python/program01.py in opacity(self, x, y, t)
155             for i in range(w):
156                 #d = abs(self.immagine[j][i].x - x) + abs(self.immagine[j][i].y - y) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][0] - self.immagine[y][x][0]) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][1] - self.immagine[y][x][1]) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][2] - self.immagine[y][x][2])
--> 157                 d = abs(self.get_pixel(x, x) - x) + abs(self.get_pixel(y, y) - y) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][0] - self.get_pixel[y][x][0]) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][1] - self.immagine[y][x][1]) + abs(self.immagine[j][i][2] - self.immagine[y][x][2])
158                 self.immagine[j][i][3] = (d*self.immagine[j][i][3])/(d + t)
159 

/home/user/Scrivania/python/program01.py in get_pixel(self, x, y)
145 
146     def get_pixel(self, x, y):
--> 147         if image.inside(x, y, self.immagine):
148             return self.immagine[y][x]
149         else:

/home/user/Scrivania/python/image.pyc in inside(img, i, j)
 78     '''Ritorna True se il pixel (i, j) e' dentro l'immagine img, False
 79     altrimenti'''
---> 80     w, h = len(img[0]), len(img)
 81     return 0 <= i < w and 0 <= j < h
 82 

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Where the function inside of the image.pyc packet is:

```
def inside(img, i, j):
w, h = len(img[0]), len(img)
return 0 <= i < w and 0 <= j < h
```

Comment: Where are you actually getting the error?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback! Thanks!

Comment: when I run the "subtraction" in the formula to calculate d

Comment: it returned to me only this error

Comment: no, @halex, it return me the same error, thank you.

Comment: **Please** show the actual, full error, with the traceback that identifies exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: is definitely on the first two subtractions, because if you try to delete the first two gives me another error again:
'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
(like the first two mean abs (self.get_pixel (x, x) - x) + abs (self.get_pixel (y, y) - y))

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit slow, and if I'm wrong format, adjust you, thank you

Comment: I found the error (although it now returns me another error, but I try to play it over and see if I can fix it :P ):

Pretty much my mistake was in passing the parameters to the function `inside()` (Package `image`), because the function takes as its first argument the image, and instead function `get_pixel()` I passed the integer `x`, in fact it would say that `int object has no attribute __getitem __`

thanks to all: D

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

- `get_pixel()` returns a `Pixel` instance, but you try to substract that with an `int`. So when you do `self.get_pixel(x, x) - x`, this runs the `Pixel.__sub__` method with `other=x`, where `x` is an integer. Therefore, when it tries to access `other.r`, it fails, as `other` is an integer rather than an object with the `r` attribute.
- `self.get_pixel[y][x][0]` won't work: `self.get_pixel` is a method. You probably mean `self.get_pixel(y, x).r`.

Comment: oops, thanks for making me notice it the second error, it was a distraction, I meant to write `abs (self.immagine [j] [i] [0] - self.immagine [y] [x] [0])`.  and the first error how can I correct? how can I do a subtraction between an object pixel and an integer? Thanks.

Comment: @rave I don't know that, it depends of what it means for you to substract an integer from a pixel :) But according to your formula, don't you mean `abs(j - x) + abs(i - y)` instead of `abs(self.get_pixel(x, x) - x) + abs(self.get_pixel(y, y) - y)`?